# Passing Parameters From Excel Value in Cell to to SQL Server via SSMS v19.1

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms

I recently installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) v 19.1. The SQL Server Native Client (SNAC) 11 has been removed from this version. I have several Excel (365) workbooks and templates that use this connection to query our SQL Server using parameter values from a cell. The queries now fail as they cannot find the SNAC connection.

I have been searching for days on how to connect to the SSMS using a query that passes a parameter but cannot figure out how to do it. Whenever I create a query/connection, the Parameters option in the Properties/Definition window is always greyed out.

For example, my query might be (Sample_Location is a value from a cell):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [CCR].[SampleData]
WHERE (SampleType = ‘Chemical’) AND (Sample_Location is ?)
```

My previous connection (`Connection1`) string might be:

```
Description=CCR_Query;DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=SQL-CSC;UID=MyName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office;WSWS=CSCENG022020;DATABASE=CCRDR;
```

How can I reestablish a connection to this database and pass the parameter? BTW, I am a user of the SQL Server database that is controlled by our IT department. If I need special permission to do certain things to the database/server, please include instructions as to what to tell our IT folks. As of yet, they have not found a solution (they don’t have many instances where users connect via Excel).

Thanks.

Comment: I would imagine you just need to install SNAC again. See [sql-server-native-client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client) and [installing-sql-server-native-client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/installing-sql-server-native-client) I suppose you could also try downgrading your ssms to 18. SSMS has nothing to do with your query, but it does appear that installing ver. 19 might be the reason SNAC was uninstalled.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using SQLNCLI anymore, it was deprecated in 2012, doesn't support anything after SQL Server 2014 and stopped being shipped with SQL Server 2022. It's long past time you switch to either the latest [ODBC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) or [OLEDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) driver.

Comment: I realize that I need to use something other than SQLNCLI. I just don't know how to replicate passing a parameter in Excel using a different connection type. Instructions on how to pass an Excel parameter to pull data from a SQL Server table(s) without SQLNCLI is something I cannot find instructions for.

Comment: OLEDB  and ODBC (unless I recall incorrectly) both use `?` as parameter markers as well, so the syntax is identical.